# How to load data from existing S3 bucket in dataiku?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dataiku

I want to load data from my Amazon S3 bucket into Dataiku to process them. Yet, if Dataiku seems to have a connector with S3 buckets:

[image]

I don't know how to add my own S3 connection:

[image]

It seems that I also can use the usual APIs to have DSS read the files for you: create a S3 connection in the administration settings. But I don't know where they are.

Comment: Perhaps: [Amazon S3 — Dataiku DSS 9.0 documentation](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/connecting/s3.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can [add an S3 connector](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/connecting/s3.html#create-a-s3-connection) with [custom installation](https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/installation/custom/index.html).
Since you are using [Dataiku online](https://www.dataiku.com/product/dataiku-as-a-managed-service/), you need to login to [the Launchpad](https://launchpad-dku.app.dataiku.io/), add a feature in your space and define S3 connection from there:

[image: img: howto add a feature]